# 500 Error for Nodejs app deployed on AWS Lightsail

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache2, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to set up a Nodejs app using AWS Lightsail following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sharmasha2nk/aws-lightsail-bitnami-nodejs-letsencrypt-cf653573b8a1).

I run my node and Apache servers in the backend, but I am returned an "Internal Server Error" when I try to access the public IP given by AWS.

If my node server isn't running, then I am returned a 503 error instead of 500 and running `curl http://localhost:3000` in the console connected to my instance, I am returned the expected response.

Does anyone know where the log files are stored in the Lightsail instance to view why the 500 errors are persisting? Thanks.

Comment: Did you follow the steps as is in the tutorial or did you add your own code to the server?

Comment: I followed the steps as in the tutorial with an expressjs hello world app.